# Can Akka-HTTP do HTTP/2.0?

Tags: http2, akka-http

sounds like a straightforward question, but i cannot find the answer (probably because the '2.0' is interpreted as Akka's version when searching for 'how to do HTTP/2.0 with Akka-HTTP').

it seems like akka-http does have a construct for HttpProtocols, but it only has HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1.

Comment: AFAIK Akka http is not yet compliant with HTTP/2.0.

Comment: recently akka-http2-support has appeared on master branch of akka-http project https://github.com/akka/akka-http . Seems soon it will be available.

Comment: It does support http2 http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/release-notes.html#akka-http2-support

Comment: @juanpavergara The link you provide says "(not yet surfaced in user API)". Akka-http 10.0.5 does _not_ yet support HTTP/2  https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/244

Answer (score 4):

The support is now official. Akka has a server side in preview mode for the moment :

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/http2.html

Comment: Why is it still in preview mode 2.5 years later?

Answer (score 1):

Akka-http 10.0.5 does not support HTTP/2, yet. You can track the work [here](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/244).

Comment: Update: "For reference, people interested in tracking progress and helping out should track this tag on github: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/labels/t%3Ahttp2 " (from https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/111 )

Answer (score 1):

Akka-http 10.1.1 supports server-side HTTP/2 in preview mode (HTTPS only):
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/http2.html

@akauppi's link still shows many features are still in progress (including client side support)

Client http/2 support appears rare among all Scala libraries currently - checkout (for both client and server side http/2):
https://github.com/criteo/lolhttp